# Parsing datetime to UTC

Tags: android, simpledateformat, utc, datetime-parsing

I have this date => 2017-10-17 10:23:30 UTC TIME

I'm parsing it like this

```
    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault(); // +03:00
    dateFormat.setTimeZone(tz);

    Date parsed_date = dateFormat.parse("2017-10-17 10:23:30");
```

but this gives me this

> Tue Oct 17 13:23:30 GMT+03:00 2017

I want this

> 2017-10-17 01:23:30

What's the problem?

Comment: What's the input type which you want to convert to the format ?

Comment: THIS date is 2017-10-17 10:23:30 in UTC it should be 2017-10-17 01:23:30

Comment: since my UTC offset is +3

Comment: It’s easy to get confused with the old and now long outdated classes `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` that Android offers built-in. It’s worth considering getting the modern Java date and time API in **ThreeTen ABP**. This will allow more natural and straightforward code for the job. See [this question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Comment: //you need to change the "hh" to "HH"
private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");//changed hh to HH so that you can have 12 hour format.
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault(); // +03:00
    dateFormat.setTimeZone(tz);

    Date parsed_date = dateFormat.parse("2017-10-17 10:23:30");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you guys for your help that's what i wonted i turn out that if the date in UTC you should start with parsing in the utc format that will keep the date as its the for formating it to your local timezone format it with local time zone

```
   private String getDate(String dateString) {
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
            formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
            Date value = null;
            try {
                value = formatter.parse(dateString);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");
            dateFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
            String dt = dateFormatter.format(value);

            return dt;
        }
```

Comment: If your hours are on a 24 hours clock (0 through 23), you want capital `HH` in the format pattern strings. Lowercase `hh` is for hour within AM or PM (1 through 12).

Answer (score 0):

A `Date` does not have a time zone. So your parsing works since Tue Oct 17 13:23:30 GMT+03:00 2017 is the same point in time as 2017-10-17 10:23:30 UTC.

The time zone is only added when you try to print a date. For example:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

Date parsed_date= dateFormat.parse("2017-10-17 10:23:30");
String strDate = dateFormat.format(parsed_date);
System.out.println(strDate);
```

prints:

```
2017-10-17 10:23:30
```

Update: to show a date in another format / time-zone you can use something like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

Date parsed_date= dateFormat.parse("2017-10-17 10:23:30");

SimpleDateFormat printFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
printFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+3"));
String strDate = printFormat.format(parsed_date);
System.out.println(strDate);
```

This prints:

```
2017-10-17 01:23:30
```

Comment: Okey , but how can i get the date that i wanted above ?

Comment: I mean the parse always return a Date, where do i get the date to print from

Comment: Use the same dateFormat to print the date.

Comment: Can you add a sample to print >2017-10-17 01:23:30

Comment: @Henry Man the date from the server is in UTC format  2017-10-17 10:23:30 when i pares it with my local utc offset it should be 2017-10-17 01:23:30 since my uTC offset is +3

Comment: @iMyth I don't get that. Where does the 9 hour difference come from?

Comment: will its 3 H but the first date is printed 24 H format and the second should be in 12 and i put "hh" and it still print  13 for 24 format i don't know why

Comment: @Henry How can we convert a utc datetime to 12 H format in local UTC timezone in android that a clearer question i think ?

Comment: @Henry this will work only in my time zone > (TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+3"))

Comment: @iMyth why? You can use any time zone. Or the default time zone if you leave out the setTimezone call.

Comment: what the point ,, this should auto detected the time difference between countries since it a messaging app and that date for each message

Comment: @iMyth  ... leave out the setTimezone call

Comment: i did that nothing ,, it printed the server utc time without adding my country offset +3